# How to create a hyperlink insertion modal without losing text selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

I've got a React site which uses Slate-React (https://docs.slatejs.org/libraries/slate-react) to create a rich text input field. Slate uses the browser's `prompt()` function to apply hyperlinks to selected text, but I need to be able to style the prompt modal so I have to find an alternative. However, if I create a simple Javascript popup with an input field, the selected text is deselected as soon as the focus is applied to the modal so no link is inserted.

Is there a way to move focus to another element whilst still keeping the original text selected?

Essentially I'm trying to emulate the Insert Hyperlink functionality/styling that Google Docs uses:
[image: Google Docs Add Hyperlink Modal]

Answer (score 0):

you can have this selection in state, and pass some prop using this selection to apply link on this selection. You can do this by using `Transforms.select(editor, thisSelection)` followed by applying link

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard, especially if you are making an accessible modal that captures input.  We have something like the following:

```js
const handleSave = (inputText: string, url: string, caretPosition: number, remove = false) => {
        let removalOffset = 0;
        let prevPath = null;
        if (remove && Path.hasPrevious(linkPath)) {
          prevPath = Path.previous(linkPath);
          const prevNode = Node.first(editor, prevPath)[0];
          removalOffset = Node.string(prevNode).length;
        }
        Transforms.insertText(editor, inputText, { at: { path: linkPath, offset: 0 } });
        Transforms.delete(editor, {
          at: {
            anchor: { path: linkPath, offset: inputText.length },
            focus: { path: linkPath, offset: text.text.length + inputText.length }
          }
        });
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          remove ? { link: undefined, url: undefined, linkOpen: undefined } : { linkOpen: undefined, url },
          { at: linkPath }
        );
        handleClose();
        if (!remove) {
          setPointer(inputText, caretPosition, linkPath);
        } else if (prevPath !== null) {
          setPointer(inputText, removalOffset + caretPosition, prevPath);
        }
};
```

The setPointer function calls `Transforms.select`. However, you may need to run it asynchronously if you are capturing inputs in the modal for accessibility.